# Call a subclass method from superclass which is not available in another sub class

Tags: java

I have a superclass `Person` and two subclasses `Author` and `Member` as follows

```
public class Author extends Person {    
  public Author(String fName, String lName, int noOfPublications){
      ----// set 
  }    
   public String getnoOfPub(){
     return noOfPublications;
  }
}

public class Member extends Person {

public Member(String fName, String lName, int memberNo){
----// set 
}    
 public String getMembNo(){
        return memberNo;
    }
}
```

I want to access the non common methods from main class or How can I get access to getnoOfPub and getMembNo methods from superclass person?

Answer (score 1):

You can gain access to the non-common methods by checking the type of the object and casting it to the type of the relevant sub-class, but that's not something you'd want to do in the code of the base class.

In a method of Person, you can write :

```
public void someMethod ()
{
    String id = null;
    if (this instanceof Member) {
        Member member = (Member) this;
        id = member.getMembNo ();
    }
}
```

While this is valid syntax, it's a very bad practice, since the base class shouldn't know about its sub-classes, since the sub-classes can be written long after the base-class was written, so the writers of the base-class can't assume they know all the sub-classes that would extend their base-class.

Answer (score 0):

it is difficult to answer the question because it is very broad. but i'll answer the common mistakes:

1. it might be that you want a method in the superclass to be override in the sub class.
2. you need to cast from `Person` to the subclasses `Member` or `Author` and the use your methods.
3. you need to initiate a variable of `Member` or `Author` and then use the methods.
4. not very likely but might be - you want the method to be static